# Installing Nvidia drivers causes a very slow shutdown

Tags: drivers, nvidia, shutdown, 17.10

So I'm having trouble installing and configuring Nvidia drivers.

My specs are:

- Intel Core i5-6200U with Intel HD Graphics 520
- NVIDIA Geforce 940MX
- **Not using Wayland**
- **Using Xorg (due to Wayland not playing nicely with Nvidia cards)**

The first thing I did with a fresh install of Ubuntu was open a terminal and typed *ubuntu-drivers devices*. I then installed the recommended package of **nvidia-384**. I'm able to switch between graphics card through NVIDIA X Server Settings.

I then installed **bumblebee & bumblebee-nvidia** since my device is Optimus enabled. Afterwords I then edited */etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf* to point to nvidia-384 instead of nvidia-current. (Which I read you have to do to get bumblebee working.) (It wasn't working when I started writing, but it's working now)

This is when I run into a few problems. I can't shutdown the machine. Shutting down the machine leaves the machine in a permanent blank screen. All I see is a blank screen with a blinking cursor on the top left. I'm forced to turn off the machine manually by holding the power button, but I would rather not do that from now on. Logging in however works fine.

Removing and purging the Nvidia drivers solves the problem, but I much rather get shutting down the machine working with the drivers installed.

Any help is appreciated. If you guys need any info, I'll do what I can to provide it.

Edit: [CTRL+Alt+F7 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC61D.jpg)

Edit: Bumblebee broke again. I'm not exactly sure what I did to get it working before. Error message:

```
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not enable discrete graphics card
```

[**Turns out their was an issue with TLP. Bumblebee works now.**](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5m78zz/bumblebee_nvidia_error_on_optimus_laptop/)

Edit: Logging in with the Nvidia prime profile causes a login loop.

Comment: What happens if when at the black screen  you go `ctrl+alt+F7`

Comment: I added an image at the bottom of the post to to show what happens when I press ctrl+alt+F7.